# Is there a way in Sublime Text to display find results in a panel at the bottom of the current window?

Tags: notepad++, eclipse, find, text-editors, sublime-text-2

This is a highly useful feature in other editors eg. Eclipse and Notepad++

You get to see the list of find results printed as all the containing lines with their lines in the buffer, which gives you some context, and shows you how the results are grouped by file and line number.

Another absolute killer feature would be "find all in current file".

**Eclipse example:**
[image: Example Eclipse view of search in current file with results in a panel at the bottom. (c) Avi Silver 2014]

**Notepad+ Example:**
[image: Example Notepad++ view of search in current file with results in a panel at the bottom. (c) Avi Silver 2014]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same question as you and solved it with anazimok's comment in the link below.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15929527/search-results-panel-for-sublimetext-2:

> You could use Find All and then Cmd+F2 to set bookmarks.
>
> The Find Result Panel is for Find In Files. Cmd+Shift+F uncheck "Use Buffer" option and you would see the Find Result Panel.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged because if the link disappears or is unavailable, your answer would have no value.  On these kinds of answers, please post a synopsis of the key points and add the link for further reference.  In this case, that answer was a single sentence.  I'll go ahead and add it to your answer.

Comment: Just had exactly the same issue finding the "find all results pane" available only for "find in files". Saved my day. ;) Anyway its pretty confusing to not get a list when hitting the `Find all` button but using `CTRL`+`F` restricting to `<current file>` in `Where` serves pretty much the wanted output.

Comment: **`CTRL+SHIFT+F`** of course, sorry

Comment: Note when using the "Find in Files" approach, clicking the ... (ellipse) button next to the "Where" field allows you to "Add current file".  Thanks to elecjack for the idea: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42127720/110126

Answer (score 4):

I'm having the same problem with Sublime.

`Ctrl + F` will only display one result at a time, and you need to hit enter to get the next result

Combination of **`Ctrl + Shift + F`** is the right answer.

A new tab will open with the all search result just like notepad++

Answer (score 1):

You can use Virtual studio code

Like this:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

At Sublime use menu FIND -> FIND IN FILES or shortcut CTRL + SHIFT + F. At search frame unmark the option "Use Buffer", the search will bring all texts results for files on selected folder. To close the panel just press ESC

Answer (score -2):

If you show the result in sublime text then two way is there

1)

```
     GOTO tools menu and click on built   tools>built
```

2)

```
    use short-cut    ctrl+B
```

Comment: The question have nothing to do with the "build" tool.